# Why is my array only printing half my values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to read data from a one column csv file. The word vermont appears 35 times but the code is only outputting 17. I can send the Csv File by Direct message or email if needed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csvtxt {

   public static void main(String a[]){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String strLine = "";
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_1111 - customers_export_1.csv"));
         while (strLine != null)
         {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            sb.append(strLine);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine==null)
               break;
            list.add(strLine);
         }

         String wordToSearchFor3 = "Vermont";
         int Vermont = 0;
         for(String Vermont1 : list)
         {
            if(Vermont1.equals(wordToSearchFor3)) 
            {
               Vermont++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Vermont = " + "["+ Vermont +"]");
         //
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
         br.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("File not found");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output I'm getting.

```
Vermont = [17]
[Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont]
```

Comment: You are calling readLine() twice in the loop and add one line to your string builder and one to the list you have, this is of course wrong. Delete the second readLine call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only getting half of the matches because you're calling the `br.readLine()` method twice in each iteration, therefore you use one return value for the null check and another one in `sb.append()`.

Your loop could be reformulated as follows, in order to use the same return value in both places:

```
    while (strLine != null)
    {
        strLine = br.readLine();
        if (strLine==null)
            break;
        sb.append(strLine);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        list.add(strLine);
    }
```

The above can be made more concise by using this somewhat ugly syntax:

```
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(strLine);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        list.add(strLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `br.readLine` twice, skipping half of the lines. And risking that the after-last line `null` is used.

Easier it is to use [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

```
Path path = Paths.get(
    "C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_1111 - customers_export_1.csv");
try {
    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

This will not add the line separator to every line (which could be `\n` or `\r\n` or even something else).

Instead of reading an entire List before looping through all lines, one could do:

```
final String wordToSearchFor3 = "Vermont";
int vermont = 0;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    vermont = (int) lines.filter(line -> line.equals(wordToSearchFor3))
                         .count();
} catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println(path + ": " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This try-with-resources syntax will ensure the AutoCloseable `lines` is always closed, even on an IOException.